# How to get rid off the "default" property when loading modules with SystemJS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amd, systemjs, es6-module-loader

I have an [AMD module](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) which I want to load with [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs). I am able to do this but unfortunately I have to call it like this:

```
var Logdown = module.default;
var instance = new Logdown('Test');
```

I would like to skip making a call to `.default`, but I don't know how to get rid off this property. I think that this `default` is somehow assigned by the SystemJS loader.

This is my module:

**logdown.js**

```
define('Logdown', function() {
  function Logdown(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  Logdown.prototype.log = function() {
    console.log(this.name);
  };

  return Logdown;
});
```

And here is my SystemJS configuration:

```
SystemJS.config({
  baseURL: '/dist',
  map: {
    'logdown': 'lib/dynamic/logdown/logdown.js'
  }
});
```

Comment: What you have in logdown.js is called 'named module' in the [AMD spec](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#namedmodules) you linked to, and that document says "You should avoid naming modules yourself, and only place one module in a file while developing. However, for tooling and performance, a module solution needs a way to identify modules in built resources."  For SystemJS, having named module in `logdown.js` turns that file into a bundle, not a module. And your question is impossible to answer without seeing complete source code that imports that module.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, artem. ☺

Comment: `default` is not created by the module loader, but rather by the export declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Use the `import ... from "...";` syntax instead of `import ... = require("...");` when using [named AMD modules](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#namedmodules) in TypeScript code.

**Explanation**

My main application (using the `Logdown` module) is written in TypeScript and compiled to ES5 code. With this setup I noticed that there is a difference in the output depending on the TypeScript import syntax used.

Here are the differences:

```
import Logdown from "logdown";

export default class Main {

  constructor(message: string) {
    let logger: Logdown = new Logdown('Test');
    logger.log();
  }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
System.register(["logdown"], function(exports_1, context_1) {
  "use strict";
  var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
  var logdown_1;
  var Main;
  return {
    setters: [
      function(logdown_1_1) {
        logdown_1 = logdown_1_1;
      }],
    execute: function() {
      Main = (function() {
        function Main(message) {
          var logger = new logdown_1.default('Test');
          logger.log();
        }

        return Main;
      }());
      exports_1("default", Main);
    }
  }
});
```

And:

```
import Logdown = require("logdown");

export default class Main {

  constructor(message: string) {
    let logger: Logdown = new Logdown('Test');
    logger.log();
  }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
System.register(["logdown"], function(exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var Logdown;
    var Main;
    return {
        setters:[
            function (Logdown_1) {
                Logdown = Logdown_1;
            }],
        execute: function() {
            Main = (function () {
                function Main(message) {
                    var logger = new Logdown('Test');
                    logger.log();
                }
                return Main;
            }());
            exports_1("default", Main);
        }
    }
});
```

**The important part** is that when using `import Logdown from "logdown";`, the compiled TypeScript code will create new instances like this `var logger = new logdown_1.default('Test');`.

But when using `import Logdown = require("logdown");`, then the compiled TypeScript code does not add a `default` property but instead creates instances like this: `var logger = new Logdown('Test');`.

So with the module type I have (a [named AMD module](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#namedmodules)), I need to use the `import ... from "...";` synatx.

Answer (score 0):

When bundling with webpack before, you could just add the `esModule` property with the value of `false` to the loaders configuration (if supported).

For example, with the html-loader, follow: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/#esmodule